# Android studio responsive design when creating layout programatically?

Tags: android

I am creating a layout programatically because it is so dependent on **data requests**, but because of this I can't use the different layouts (small, xlarge etc) to make my design responsive for different device screens. I made a java **extention file** that has a function which gets the device's screen width and height so i can pass in a percent value and returns it in **px**. Is this viable or is there any good way to go about this?

Comment: `I am creating a layout programtically because it is so dependent on data requests`, are you sure about this? xml layouts are very flexible, i've never seen any logical reason to create a layout programatically

Comment: The only this I have is a container of RelativeLayout and I just add views to it programatically.

Comment: @marmor For example, I want to create one relative layout per day in month, so that may be 31 but may also be 28 if its february.

Comment: you can create a container layout in xml, and that relative-layout in a different xml, and programatically inflate it 28-31 times, each time inserting it to the container layout in the appropriate place

Comment: I will look into inflating viewgroups then, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should go for ConstraintLayout. It has been designed for Responsive UI. It is more flexible and you can easily design using Android Studio's Layout Editor. Make sure you are using the latest version of Android Studio.

Learn more here: https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html